# how to split dataframe cells using delimiter into different dataframes. with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

There are other questions on the same topic and they helped but I have an extra twist.

I have a dataframe with multiple values in each (but not all) cells.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["10-30-410","20-40-500","25-50"], 'b':["5-8-9","4", "99"]})
```

| index | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10-30-410 | 5-8-9 |
| 1 | 20-40-500 | 4 |
| 2 | 25-50 | 99 |

How can I split each cell by the dash "-" and create three new dataframes? Note that not all cells have multiple values, in which case the second and third dataframes get NA or blank (treating these as strings).

So I need df1 to be the first of those values:

| index | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | 20 | 4 |
| 2 | 25 | 99 |

And df2 would be:

| index | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 30 | 8 |
| 1 | 40 |  |
| 2 | 50 |  |

And likewise for df3:

| index | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 410 | 9 |
| 1 | 500 |  |
| 2 |  |  |

I got df1 with this

```
df1 = df.replace(r'(\d+).*(\d+).*(\d+)+', r'\1', regex=True)
```

But df2 doesn't quite work. I get the second values but also 4 and 99, which should be blank.

```
df2 = df.replace(r'(\d+)-(\d+).*', r'\2', regex=True)
```

| index | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 30 | 8 |
| 1 | 40 | 4 - should be blank |
| 2 | 50 | 99 - should be blank |

Is this the right approach? I'm pretty good on regex but fuzzy with groups. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) + [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) + [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) to get the data in a more usable format:

```
new_df = pd.concat(
    (df['a'].str.split('-', expand=True),
     df['b'].str.split('-', expand=True)),
    keys=('a', 'b'),
    axis=1
).stack(dropna=False).droplevel(0)
```

`new_df`:

```
      a     b
0    10     5
1    30     8
2   410     9
0    20     4
1    40  None
2   500  None
0    25    99
1    50  None
2  None  None
```

Expandable option for `n` cols:

```
cols = ['a', 'b']
new_df = pd.concat(
    (df[c].str.split('-', expand=True) for c in cols),
    keys=cols,
    axis=1
).stack(dropna=False).droplevel(0)
```

---

Then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) level 0 + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) to create a list of dataframes:

```
dfs = [g.reset_index(drop=True) for _, g in new_df.groupby(level=0)]
```

`dfs`:

```
[    a   b
0  10   5
1  20   4
2  25  99,
     a     b
0  30     8
1  40  None
2  50  None,
       a     b
0   410     9
1   500  None
2  None  None]
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ["10-30-410", "20-40-500", "25-50"],
    'b': ["5-8-9", "4", "99"]
})

cols = ['a', 'b']
new_df = pd.concat(
    (df[c].str.split('-', expand=True) for c in cols),
    keys=cols,
    axis=1
).stack(dropna=False).droplevel(0)

dfs = [g.reset_index(drop=True) for _, g in new_df.groupby(level=0)]

print(dfs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with `filter`:

```
k = pd.concat((df[c].str.split('-', expand=True).add_prefix(c+ '-')
               for c in df.columns), 1).fillna('')
df1 = k.filter(like='0')
df2 = k.filter(like='1')
df3 = k.filter(like='2')
```

`NOTE`: To strip the digit from columns use : `k.filter(like='0').rename(columns= lambda x: x.split('-')[0])`